# Should .github worflow yml files be ignored?

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, gitignore

Hope you are all doing great :)

This is a simple question, that I found no answer to, online. Should .github/workflow actions (yml files) be added to gitignore?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.gitignore` exists to avoid committing certain files to the repository.

`.github/workflow` files are usually used to tell GitHub to execute actions. GitHub only knows about files that are *committed to your repository*.

Hence, it makes no sense to add those files to your `.gitignore` since you *specifically* want them to be in your repository.