# Prevent github workflow files in fork being included in pull request back to base repository

Tags: git, github, github-actions

I have created a fork of another repository, and have made changes to various files.  Normally, to create a pull request to ask the owner of the base repository to review/include these changes in the base repo, I click on the link in "This branch is 21 commits ahead of base_repo:main", and create a pull request from there.

But this time, I have also created some workflow files which are in `.github/workflows` of my fork.  Not that I mind sharing these back to the base repo, but my understanding is that if I do, the base repo will end up triggering lots of actions (every time a push is made to the `main` branch), which will fail in this case because they rely on secrets that will only be in my fork (I assume that repo secrets in a fork are not copied back to the base as part of a pull request??)... but it will still be messy for the Actions part of the base repo.

So how do I prevent these workflow files (which are mainly useful to me and me only) being sent up to base?  I thought about excluding the workflow folder via the `.gitignore` file, but apparently this [isn't a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71818738/4070848).

Comment: Why not letting those workflows files on the default branch (on your forked repository) and update the other files on another branch without those workflows? That way, you could open a PR from the other branch to the origin repository without the workflow files.

Comment: @GuiFalourd yes I suppose I could, but I thought that there might be a way setting up workflows in GitHub which changed this behaviour, because somehow I feel that workflow files should be given a different treatment to normal files, because different users will have different workflows for their own specific needs.  Anyhow, perhaps using a branch as you suggest is the only (and correct) approach.

Comment: I understand the workflow should already be available from the `origin` repository, for the `forked` one to use them as well, setting specific secrets in each repository. You could suggest those workflows through another PR to the origin repository and see if the code owners find them interesting or not, for all contributors to use them.

Comment: @GuiFalourd having tried to implement this, and not having much experience using branches, I'm uncertain how it would work.  When I'm working on my fork, I want my own workflows to be operating on my latest code... so if my workflows are on one branch but my updated code is on another branch, then how does it work in testing like this?